# How can I separate gulp-template code from underscore template code?

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js, gulp, lodash

I'm using gulp to build my project, and part of my project utilizes Underscore templates. One of the plugins I'm using during my build process is gulp-template, which uses Lodash templates.

Is it possible to denote which code should be rendered when I use gulp, and which code should be ignored for templating?

As an example, I have a file that contains:

```
<script src="<%= image_server_url %>/scripts/iep-alert/alert-content.js"></script>
```

During the build, I want `image_server_url` to be rendered. However, elsewhere in my project I have this code that I want to be ignored by the `gulp-template` plugin:

```
<%
    if(alert.disability === "true") {
%>
    <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Disability: </span><%= alert.disability %></li>
<%
    }
%>
```

Right now, when I invoke the gulp task that calls gulp-template, I get `ReferenceError: alert is not defined` because the context for the gulp-template does not include `alert` -- only `image_server_url` is part of the context for gulp-template.

EDIT: I have edited my code to match `{{ image_server_url}}`, and I changed my call to `gulp-template` to look like this:

```
template({
    image_server_url: config.dev.image_server_url
}, {
    interpolate: /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g
})
```

With those changes, when I run my `build` task, I think `gulp-template` is still trying to run code within `<%` and `%>` blocks because I get this error:

`window is not defined`

the code it's trying to run within the first `<% JS block %>`

```
<%
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('admin') != -1) {
%>
```

If someone has a solution to this particular problem, great. I think for now I'm going to research an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess) plugin. My code looks like this now and it's working well so far.

```
<script src="<!-- @echo IMAGE_SERVER_URL -->/scripts/iep-alert/alert.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can find no sane way to do this, since you want to parse the *same* template *twice*, only some strings have to be interpolated in gulp, others in the browser.

A suggestion is to use the `_.templateSettings`, so that in the gulp processing, you can use another template format.

For exemple in gulp, you'd set :

`_.templateSettings.interpolate = /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g;`

And in your template :

`<script src="{{ image_server_url }}/scripts/iep-alert/alert-content.js">`

So, when the template is intented to be processed by gulp, use the `{{}}` interpolation syntax, and when it's intented to be processed browser side, use the default (erb) `<%= %>` syntax.

Comment: Where do I set `interpolate`? Does that go somewhere in my `gulpfile`?

Comment: Since I'm only using the gulp-template plugin to interpolate a string, is there a better way to approach this than using a full templating system like Lodash?